# Android - ResourceNotFoundException and NumberFormatException

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I have created an app in which I've used `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` along with `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

When I run this app on a Samsung Tablet Neo (Android version 4.2.2), the app is running perfectly.

But when I run the same app on Google Nexus 5 (Android version 6.0.1), I'm getting `ResourceNotFoundException` and the app just crashes on the starting line of the following code in my Java (Activity) file.

The app crashes on this line: `setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);`

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
rocess: com.myapp, PID: 11761
va.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivityWithNavigationViewExpandableList}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f0c00ab
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
aused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f0c00ab
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2750)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2699)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:485)
  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:746)
  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:671)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:54)
  at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:756)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
  at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:78)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:223)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
  at com.myapp.MainActivityWithNavigationViewExpandableList.onCreate(MainActivityWithNavigationViewExpandableList.java:64)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
aused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "0.70000005dip"
  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
  at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:323)
  at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFloat(TypedArray.java:396)
  at android.content.res.ColorStateList.inflate(ColorStateList.java:275)
  at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:222)
  at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:201)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2746)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2699) 
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:485) 
  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:746) 
  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:671) 
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62) 
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58) 
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:54) 
  at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:756) 
  at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261) 
  at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243) 
  at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:78) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:223) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130) 
  at com.myapp.MainActivityWithNavigationViewExpandableList.onCreate(MainActivityWithNavigationViewExpandableList.java:64) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I searched other SO answers as well.

The resource '**abc_hint_foreground_material_dark**' is not in my '**color**'. This resource should come from Support Library of Android, which I'm using in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I digged more in the issue and my suspect was `NumberFormatException`. I searched for decimal values in my `dimens.xml` file and commented them. And it worked fine now. Basically, Android was unable to parse the decimal values placed in `dimens.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

`abc_hint_foreground_material_dark` is a link to the theme's `foreground_material_dark`, see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/res/color/abc_hint_foreground_material_dark.xml).

The `NumberFormatException` says that this color value is invalid ('Invalid float: "0.70000005dip"'). This value does not come from support library so must have been set by your resources (check colors.xml and values.xml). Color values should be hex integers and are not in dp or any other unit. See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) for more info.

Comment: But I do not find "android/platform/frameworks/support/master/./v7/appcompat/res/color/" in my project. I have added "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' in my module level gradle file. This should take care of it. Isn't it?

Comment: It'll be compiled with the support library, but it doesn't matter. You need to check your resources for `foreground_material_dark`

Comment: I manually added the file 'foreground_material_dar.xml" file under 'res/color/' directory in my Android Studio project. But it's still crashing and giving the same error.

Comment: Post your colors.xml and any other xmls that contain color definitions

Comment: Please see the screenshot in the given link as I do not have sufficient permission to upload an image here. https://ibb.co/nKrstk